# How can I migrate taxonomy data from an outdated site?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I have a site building with an old version of D8. The site can not run up and all I get is a backup `sql` file. So I'm creating a new D8 site with the latest version, trying to restore the data.  When I trying to restore the taxonomy data, I import the related tables from my backup sql file into the new db and fixed some "revision" fields. The imported tables are listed below:

```
taxonomy_index
taxonomy_term_data
taxonomy_term_field_data
taxonomy_term_hierarchy
```

But I still can not load any of these data from the admin ui. Is there anything else that I need  do? Or another way to restore taxonomy data?

Comment: Did you then run any database updates after you imported the old database? Like `drush -y updb` and flush cache again? Can you maybe also get hold of the old files? Then look what really caused the issue and then update incrementally?

Comment: This can be hard depending on your source D8 version, take a look at taxonomy.install, there are some updates in it. Most times it's more simple to have a small script where you create your taxonomy from a simple dump by Term::create() - and run it in Drupal context with drush.

Comment: @RainerFeike Thank you, I will take a look at taxonomy.install next time. Now I get it done by recreating all the terms manually. It seems that I was missing some data in the table named `taxonomy_term_revision__parent`.